# BeautifulSoup scraping img

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to **scrape** that [website](https://myurl.com/) for the Captcha image link.

Using browser inspect element it's already appear but upon scraping it's not shown.

My target were to getting the `img`

Below is my code which i tried with it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://myurl.com/"
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    for item in soup.findAll("img"):
        print(item)
```

Comment: The image is loaded with xhr. You can see in the page source the javascript code that loads it.

Comment: It's an `event`. Normal `soup.findAll` won't find possibly.

Comment: are there a way to extract it ?

Comment: use selenium webdriver with python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others have said, selenium will help load the img allowing you to scrape it.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'https://myurl.com/'
browser.get(url)
time.sleep(10) # wait 10 seconds for the captcha to load
html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features='html.parser')

imgs = soup.find_all('img')
for img in imgs:
    print(img)
```

Returns:

`<img alt="" id="yw1" src="/site/captcha/v/5dd3ccb47dd88/"/>`

Answer (score 1):

If you go to 'NetWork' tab you will get below link which returns the captcha image in JSON format. You don't need Selenium for that.

> https://example.com/site/captcha/refresh/1/?_=1574163338269

You need to convert response into JSON and then get the `url` key val.

```py
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = "https://example.com/site/captcha/refresh/1/?_=1574163338269"
    r = s.get(url, verify=False)
    img = r.json()
    print(img['url'])
```

**NetworkTab**

[image: screenshot[1]]

Comment: the point that this is `1/?_=1574163338269` changeable on each `request/refresh`